# minimizing for loops when iterating through multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file containing 3 columns of data (among others that aren't relevant to this question). The 3 pertinent columns are `ID`, `length`, and `day`. I'm wanting to simply calculate the average `length` for each `ID` for `day` values between 0.1 - 10.9. Each `ID` has a different amount of `day` and corresponding `length` values.

Also, I'm unclear on whether it is better to do this in pandas, or to read in the csv and convert the numeric (`day` and `length`) data to floats. Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

My current flow is included below, but it's not running (seems to be stuck in never ending for loop).

```
df = []

for row in csv.reader(open('/Users/me/Desktop/datafile.csv','r')):
    df.append(row)
header= df.pop(0)

#unzip data
ID, day, length = zip(*df)

day_float = []
def _floatday(alist):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        day_float.append(float(alist[i]))
    return (day_float)

_floatday(day)

length_float = []
def _floatlength(alist):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        length_float.append(float(alist[i]))
    return (length_float)

_floatlength(length)


avg_initial=0.0
count=0    
initial_length =[] 
for ID_val in range(len(ID)): 
    for i in range(len(day_float)): 
        for p in range(len(length_float)):
            if day_float[i] < 10.9: 
                avg_initial += p
                count += 1
                average_length = avg_initial/count
                initial_length.append(average_length)
return (initial_length)
```

I realize the functions to convert to floats are super clunky... I'm pretty new to python still. Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the `pd.read_csv` parameter `usecols` to limit to just the columns you're looking for.
2. Use `query` to filter your dataframe inline.
3. Use `groupby`/`mean`

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Desktop/datafile.csv', usecols=['ID', 'day', 'length'])
df.query('.1 <= day <= 10.9').groupby('ID').length.mean()
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is so much easier than everything I was trying! Thank you! @piRSquared

Comment: @LaurenN. no problem.  Happy Coding.